# Run model train with RPi

Tags: electronics

I am trying to figure out how to run my model HO scale train using my Raspberry Pi.  While I have found videos on YouTube of people operating their model via RPi, I can't find any way to do it myself.  Does anyone know code or the setup to get this working?

Comment: Welcome to the community.  Before you start posting, please read the [Help Center](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/asking) about asking questions.  I think you will find your question does not meet the requirements.

Comment: You will also find that there is more than just software involved.  You will have to build some electronics to enable this as well.

Answer (score 4):

I have no clue about model trains, but a quick Google search reveals that there are multiple projects for Linux which allow you to control model trains. It seems that Rocrail is one of them, and they even have a [Raspberry Pi](http://wiki.rocrail.net/doku.php?id=raspi%3araspi-dev-en) page in their wiki.

You need to fetch one of their [pre built packages](http://rocrail.net/software/rocrail-snapshot/), and install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i rocrail-xxxx-wheezy-armhf.deb
```

Where xxxx denotes the version number (5655 as of this writing). You seem to need to have a digital command station for your model train, which will be attached via ethernet or USB to the Pi. You need to figure this one out for yourself, but the Rocrail wiki seems full with information on this.

Comment: Who knew that someone already wrote it... I guess software developers need hobbies too!

Comment: That is awesome! and even though the answer seemed to broad it actually is not. This is defiantly the best answer.